# ValueError: Metric should be a callable, received

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I don't know if what I'm doing is correct. But I would like to use `logcosh` as a loss. So I put it inside a class as shown below:

```
class Logcosh(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def call(self, y_true,  y_pred ):
    return tf.keras.losses.logcosh(y_true, y_pred)
```

Then I called in my code:

```
LR = 0.0001
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

dice_loss_se2 =Logcosh()
 
mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError( )
metrics = [ mae,sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5) , dice_loss_se2]

model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss= dice_loss_se2,metrics= metrics)

LR = 0.0001
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

train_gen = DataGen(train_ids, train_path, image_size=image_size, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = DataGen(valid_ids, train_path, image_size=image_size, batch_size=batch_size)

train_steps = len(train_ids)//batch_size
valid_steps = len(valid_ids)//batch_size

history =model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, 
                    epochs=epochs)
```

But I got the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-fb657b903f55> in <module>
     23 valid_steps = len(valid_ids)//batch_size
     24 
---> 25 history =model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, 
     26                     epochs=epochs)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2207         'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.',
   2208         stacklevel=2)
-> 2209     return self.fit(
   2210         generator,
   2211         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise
ValueError: in user code:
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 864, in train_step
        return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 957, in compute_metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 438, in update_state
        self.build(y_pred, y_true)
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 358, in build
        self._metrics = tf.__internal__.nest.map_structure_up_to(y_pred, self._get_metric_objects,
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 484, in _get_metric_objects
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 484, in <listcomp>
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    File "/storage/home/mm8755/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 538, in _get_metric_object
        raise ValueError(
    ValueError: Metric should be a callable, received: <__main__.Logcosh object at 0x2b1db47964c0>
```

Comment: You would have to define function `__call__`, not `call`.  However, why not just pass `tf.keras.losses.logcosh`?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy if I call it like this "model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss= tf.keras.losses.logcosh(),metrics= metrics)" I get "TypeError: Missing required positional argument"

Comment: That is not a complete error message, what is the full traceback in that case?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy ... you are right. I was passing the loss funcation with parenthesis. When I removed the parenthesis. it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model.fit_generator is quite old but the idea is the same.

LogCosh that identifies identity as logarithms scales, how would you present similarity with limited information?

You see it has the behavior of the logarithms for the categorize tasks.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class and Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class Logcosh(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, y_true,  y_pred ):
        return tf.keras.losses.logcosh(y_true, y_pred)

def gen():
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
    train_generator = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(32, 32),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode='categorical',   # None  # categorical   # binary
        subset='training')

    return train_generator
        
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
LR = 0.000001

directory = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\"
train_steps = 33
val_steps = 1
epochs = 1500
BATCH_SIZE = 33
IMG_SIZE = (32, 32)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
train_generator = gen()
val_generator = train_generator

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.97 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((256, 32 * 32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(196, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(196)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = Logcosh()# <__main__.Logcosh object at 0x000001EFAFBB8DF0>

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[custom_callback])


PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image )
    list_file.append(image)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    image = tfio.experimental.color.rgba_to_rgb( image )
    list_file.append(image)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.title("Cat emotions recognition")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:**

[image: Sample]